# Warning: Creating default object from empty value in on line 16

Tags: php

I'm getting an error in my PHP code "Warning: Creating default object from empty value in" Here the code :

```
class carshop
{
    public $cars = array();
    public $car_brand,$car_name, $car_modal,$car_price;

    public function set_cars($car_brand,$car_name,$car_modal,$car_price)
    {

        $n_cars = count($this->cars);
```

on error line starts here:

```
        $this->cars[$n_cars]->car_brand = $car_brand;
        $this->cars[$n_cars]->car_name = $car_name;
        $this->cars[$n_cars]->car_modal = $car_modal;
        $this->cars[$n_cars]->car_price = $car_price;
    }



    public function print_cars()
    {
        echo "<b>Car Stock: </b> We Have " 
        .count($this->cars). " Cars Infromation ! </br></br>";
        for ($i=0; $i < count($this->cars) ; $i++) { 
            echo "<b><u>Car No: ".$i."</u></b> " 
            .$this->cars[$i]->car_brand. " ,"
             .$this->cars[$i]->car_name. " ,"
              .$this->cars[$i]->car_modal. " , \$"
               .$this->cars[$i]->car_price;
            echo "</br>";
        }
    }
}
```

objects starts here:

```
$shop = new carshop();
$shop->set_cars("Honda","Civic","2017",2400000);
$shop->set_cars("Honda","City","2012",1200000);
$shop->set_cars("Honda","Accord","2015",1100000);
$shop->print_cars();
```

Comment: `$this->cars` is an `array` not an `object`. You should do something like: `$this->cars[$n_cars]['car_brand'] = $car_brand;`

Answer (score 0):

`$cars` field of your `carshop` class as an array:

```
public $cars = array();
```

From the code, I presume you intended it to be an array of cars. The error occurred because you were doing this:

```
$this->cars[$n_cars]->car_brand = $car_brand;
```

But the value of `$this->cars[$n_cars]` is `null`.

Perhaps you could split your class - one to handle the business logic of a car shop, the other to represent a car. Such as the following:

```
class Car
{
    public $car_brand, $car_name, $car_modal, $car_price;
}

class CarShop
{
    public $cars = array();

    public function set_cars($car_brand,$car_name,$car_modal,$car_price)
    {
        $n_cars = count($this->cars);
        $this->cars[$n_cars] = new Car();  // <-- Create a new Car object and add it to the cars array
        $this->cars[$n_cars]->car_brand = $car_brand;
        $this->cars[$n_cars]->car_name = $car_name;
        $this->cars[$n_cars]->car_modal = $car_modal;
        $this->cars[$n_cars]->car_price = $car_price;
    }

    // ... Rest of your CarShop class here
}
```